# How to start with Blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm very interested in modelling however I only have a little bit experience in Adobe Flash Pro. I would like to start from Blender and how to make easy models then go higher and higher into more advanced models. Is there any book from which I can start from ?

I know that there are many tutorials on Google or YouTube such as this one (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uY7rjhhMs) but I prefer some solid book which will explain everything from the basics.

Thanks
Every help appreciated.

Comment: There is a wikibook called [Blender: Noob to Pro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what gandalf3 commented, the answer is check out Blender: Noob to Pro here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro

I suggest while you go through the tutorials you should freely test out any ideas you might have like "Hey what happens when I do this?", 
Also you may want to take a look and get familiar with Blender's shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain access to the entire range of official Blender training products for an affordable amount of money via the new Blender Cloud:

https://cloud.blender.org/

(scroll to the end of the page)

> Blender Cloud is a high quality web service in which we share all data of our previous films, all our training videos, and a continuous stream of data from the Gooseberry studios.
>
> [...]
>
> Blender Cloud will offer all Blender Institute Open Movie/Training DVDs.

More in-depth info:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Org:Institute/BlenderCloud

Comment: And even though the manual is incomplete and sometimes obtuse, it is worth checking out, specially for the interface and the most basic concepts: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual

Comment: Is there any official book which I can buy from Blender or Ebay ? I know there are a lot of tuts online but somehow I prefer actual book rather than online tut.

Comment: Books a quickly outdated, I wouldn't buy anything older than 1-2 years - Blender's development is too fast. The only recent book I found on Amazon is [Blender Master Class: A Hands-On Guide to Modeling, Sculpting, Materials, and Rendering](http://www.amazon.com/Blender-Master-Class-Hands--Sculpting/dp/1593274777/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1397307387&sr=1-1&keywords=blender). And there's a commercial video training: [Blender 2.6 Essentials Training](http://www.lynda.com/Blender-2-5-tutorials/Blender-2-6-Essential-Training/87088-2.html)